# Get Nested Elements using XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I'm trying to extract the errorMessage element from following xml but getting an error as it seemingly cannot find the tag. Any ideas what I've done wrong?  Many thanks

```
<order>
<orderReference>ABCD</orderReference>
<status>Error</status>
<errors>
<error>
  <errorCode>1102</errorCode>
  <errorMessage><![CDATA[ "Job with same reference already exists in      file" ]]></errorMessage>
</error>
</errors>
```

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("order"))
{
    string value = element.Element("orderReference").Value;
    string value2 = element.Element("status").Value;
    string value3 = "";
    if (value2 == "Error")
    {
        value3 = element.Element("errorMessage").Value;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(value + ' ' + value2 + ' ' + value3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
value3 = element.Descendants("errorMessage").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't access directly to a child element. you should use XPATH : errors/error/errorMessage

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("order"))
  {
        string value = element.Element("orderReference").Value;
        string value2 = element.Element("status").Value;
        string value3 = "";
        if (value2 == "Error")
        {
            value3 = element.Element("errors/error/errorMessage").Value;

        }

        Console.WriteLine(value + ' ' + value2 + ' ' + value3);
    }
```

You can also use GetElementsByTagName.

```
 value3 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("errorMessage");
```

It will return collection of nodes that includes "errorMessage"

Comment: I get error System.Xml.XmlException: 'The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: @user552769 use this: value3 = element.Element("//errors/error/errorMessage").Value;

Answer (score 0):

For VB'ers that might come across this...

```
Dim xe As XElement
'to load
'  xe = XElement.Load("path / URI")
'for testing
xe = <order>
         <orderReference>ABCD</orderReference>
         <status>Error</status>
         <errors>
             <error>
                 <errorCode>1102</errorCode>
                 <errorMessage><![CDATA[ "Job with same reference already exists in      file" ]]></errorMessage>
             </error>
         </errors>
     </order>

'get first
Dim errMess As String = xe...<errorMessage>.FirstOrDefault.Value

'get ALL <errorMessage> elements
Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe...<errorMessage>

For Each el As XElement In ie
    Debug.WriteLine(el.Value)
Next
```